# Microsoft Graph subscription failure using WebApi endpoints and Graph .net SDK

Tags: asp.net-web-api, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, webapi

We have a use case requirement for an 'always on listener' subscription to an exchange mailbox that we currently utilise EWS for. Due to the end of life of EWS, we are in the process of replacing our old EWS code with Graph.

I have followed the excellent article posted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/), with the only changes being the mapping of the NotificationUrl and LifecycleNotificationUrl endpoints, as I have published my WebApi project to our development IIS server and also to Azure App Server. I also need to renew/recreate the subscription periodically due to the 'always on' requirement and the limited lifespan of a subscription.

The issue that we are facing is with the two endpoints, as they are used for validation at the point the subscription is created. The code we are using to create the subscription is as follows:

```
var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
            sub.ChangeType = "created";
            sub.NotificationUrl = NotificationUrl + PostPath;
            sub.LifecycleNotificationUrl = NotificationUrl + LifecyclePath;
            sub.Resource = $"/users/{NotificationsEmailAddress}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages";
            sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(ExpirationMinutes);
            sub.ClientState = "clientstate";

            var newSubscription = await GraphServiceClient
                .Subscriptions
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(sub);
```

Upon creating the subscription, we intermittently receive the following error:

> Exception: Code: ValidationError Message: Subscription validation
> request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to
> validation request. Inner error:  AdditionalData:     date:
> 2022-05-31T14:12:12   request-id: 5eadfd3a-7691-4e8e-840d-368c2ed36401
> client-request-id: 5eadfd3a-7691-4e8e-840d-368c2ed36401
> ClientRequestId: 5eadfd3a-7691-4e8e-840d-368c2ed36401

However, we do eventually manage to validate against our endpoints after several retries.

The problem that we have is that upon renewing or recreating the subscription, we are **constantly** receiving the error above. The only way to re-authenticate is to stop our application completely and start again.

Has anyone else had success renewing or recreating subscriptions from the same application or WebApi project that created the original expired one?

EDIT: I have tried publishing the project to Azure App Services and have no issues renewing or recreating the subscription. We use Cloudflare to route to our servers and I am thinking that may be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Cloudflare rule that we had set up that restricted posts from certain geographic locations. The initial post was accepted as it was from a geographic location that was allowed, but subsequent renewal ones weren't

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, content type must be text/plain, and the validation token must be included in the body.

1. [CodeSamples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample)  asp .net mvc sample - Specifically look at the NotificationController.cs file In the method

```
[HttpPost]  
public async Task<ActionResult> Listen()  
{
// Validate the new subscription by sending the token back to Microsoft Graph.
// This response is required for each subscription.
if  (Request.QueryString["validationToken"]  !=  null)
{
var token =  Request.QueryString["validationToken"];
return  Content(token,  "plain/text");
}
```

2. Try to Isolate the code and call the same API with Postman/Graph Explorer and observe the results.
3. The validation request must be able to be responded to by `notificationUrl`. You should also check that the validation token is returned as plain/text. For further information, see the Notification endpoint validation [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation).

Comment: Thanks, the Validation token is getting through on first attempt but then failing on renewal or recreation. I have published to Azure App Services and i do not seem to be having the issue there, i think it is environmental